# Activate a CSS Class by an array sequence with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have 6 divs that I want to activate a heartbeat CSS animation, however, I would like to do that by a sequence.

For example, I have an array:

```
self.generatedSequence = [0,3,5,3];
```

Each item in the array means the position of the div that will receive the heartbeat function.

[image: Divs]

Each dive is a UI component from AngularJs:

```
<div class="grid-cell"
    ng-class="{'heartbeat': $ctrl.isActive
    }"
></div>
```

I'm trying to use the controller to activate the HeartBeat animation in every position by a sequence. 
So in that example will be like

- The position 0 will takes 1s
- The position 3 will takes 1s after the position 0
- The position 5 will takes 1s after the position 3
- The position 3 will takes 1s after the position 5

So all the animation will take 4s.

I tried to do that with $timeout, but it does the both at the same time.

https://codepen.io/guifeliper/pen/pwdKKj

Comment: You can use css for the whole thing, and angular just to set the animation/transition delays to set the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `$interval`, not `$timeout` since `$timeout` only runs once.

```
$ctrl.stopInterval = $interval(function () {
  $ctrl.heartbeatId = $ctrl.generatedSequence.shift();

  // be sure to clean up afterwards
  if($ctrl.generatedSequence.length == 0) {
    $interval.cancel($ctrl.stopInterval);
  }

}, 1000);
```

And change your grid cells `ng-class` directives like this:

```
<div class="grid-cell" ng-repeat="grid in $ctrl.gridBox"
    ng-class="{'heartbeat': $ctrl.heartbeatId == grid }"></div>
```

https://codepen.io/jdoyle/pen/xrPJwW

Comment: That's the exact answer that I was looking for. 
Thank you!